# Global sections of G/B and G/P

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a semi-simple algebraic group over $\mathbb C$, $B$ be a Borel and P is be parabolic containing $B$ and let $\mathcal L$ be an ample line bundle on $G/P$. Is it true that $H^0(G/B, L^{\otimes d})=H^0(G/P, L^{\otimes d})$ for all d > 0?

From the projection map from $G/B \rightarrow G/P$ we get an injection from $H^0(G/P, L^{\otimes d})$ to $H^0(G/B, L^{\otimes d})$. But why is it a surjection ?

Comment: The fiber is $P/B$.

Comment: Use the projection formula.

Comment: The morphism from $G/B$ to $G/P$ is rational.  The derived pushforward of the structure sheaf of $G/B$ is naturally equivalent to the (complex supported in degree $0$ of the) structure sheaf of $G/P$.  Combine this with the projection formula.

Comment: @Pitor: Do you allow $P$ to equal $G$?   That is technically possible for a parabolic subgroup.

Comment: No, I will assume P to be a proper parabolic subgroup of G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q. Why is it a surjection? 
A. It's a nonzero $G$-equivariant map to (by Borel-Weil) a $G$-irrep.

(Of course this has punted the difficulty, solved geometrically by the commenters, into the Borel-Weil theorem.)